# HTML autocomplete attribute in textarea

Tags: html

I have one problem with autocomplete in text area .

My form has one field is textarea element, when i fullfill this form and submit. It redirect to another page . Then when i click "back" button in chrome web browser. It back to the form, every field in this form is empty, except textarea field.

I set autocomplete attribute of textarea field `autocomplete=off`

But nothing happens

Please help me to clear input data of textarea field after user click "back" button of chrome web browser.

Comment: As far as i know autocomplete is a browser thing, im not sure u can just turn it off... Did u try setting its text/value to an empty string on page load?

Comment: @Banana: thanks you, just add set value attribute value='' and It is OK. But why don't you answer the question, so i can accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, i've added it as an answer

Answer (score -5, accepted):

As far as i know autocomplete is a browser thing, im not sure u can just turn it off... try setting its text/value to an empty string on page load

Comment: It smells like the browser kept the page "like it was before" (Firefox calls the "BFCache"). Javascript states will remain. Be careful when "patching" autocompletion like that.

Answer (score 3):

In current browsers, when you hit back or forward button,  the page is not reloaded.
If you want do something when user click back or forward button, you need to listen for [BFCache(Back-Forward Cache)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache) `pageshow` and `pagehide` events.
For example, you can reset your form when user click back or forward button like;

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
    var form = $('#your_form_id'); 
    form.reset();
});
```

Comment: Thanks you, your answer is second solution.

Answer (score 1):

'autocomplete' is a non-standard attribute.

1. To turn off autocomplete, you need to use javascript.

   ```
   if (document.getElementsByTagName) {

   var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);

   for (i=0; inputElements[i]; i++) {

   if (inputElements[i].className &&(inputElements[i].className.indexOf(“disableAutoComplete”) != -1)) {

   inputElements[i].setAttribute(“autocomplete”,”off”);

   }

   }

   }
   ```
2. Also, if you are using HTTPS site, most of the browsers will turn off autocomplete automatically.
3. Take a look at these developer sites for more info:

   - [Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533032%28VS.85%29.aspx)
   - [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)